# How to use Regex Capturing Group variable in NiFi Expression Language?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to replace a date format in all lines of text file using NiFi. The file looks like this:

```
ABCDE,20200619,23.8
FGHIJ,20200619,14.5
...
```

I am trying to do this using ReplaceText processor to change `20200619` to `2020-06-19`. I've made regex expression matching the date (`(20\d{6},)`) and I have checked that it's working: when i write `$1 TESTING,` in `Replacement value` it works as expected (single line of file looks like `ABCDE,20200619, TESTING,23.8`).

The problem is when I try to use Expression Language and `:substring` function. This is my code in `Replacement value`:

```
${$1:substring(0, 4)}-${$1:substring(4, 6)}-${$1:substring(6, 8)}
```

But I get following error:

[NiFi Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhsCC.png)

It looks like the Expression Language can't access my `$1` variable. How can I access my Regex Capturing Group variable inside Expression Language?

This is my processor:

[NiFi Processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3AIH.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer: when trying to access Regex Capturing Group inside ${...} we need to use it with apostrophes, so the code like this works:

```
${'$1':substring(0, 4)}-${'$1':substring(4, 6)}-${'$1':substring(6, 8)}
```

Comment: Good job on the post and solution.  You should be able to accept it and give yourself more rep credits.